# GTA-VC not running

Tags: wine

When I open Gta-VC with wine then my resolution comes into **800x640** and after just after a few seconds it becomes small and goes to the top left corner and becomes transparent.

When I try to open with terminal, the same thing happens.

here's the code of terminal:-

```
anshuman@anshuman-Inspiron-5521:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Vice City$ wine gta-vc.exe
0018:err:module:import_dll Library fwpkclnt.sys (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\idmwfp.sys") not found
0018:err:module:import_dll Library NETIO.SYS (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\idmwfp.sys") not found
0018:err:winedevice:async_create_driver failed to create driver L"IDMWFP": c0000142
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f604,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f624,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f434,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f874,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x20.
0009:fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unimplemented action: 59 (SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS)
0009:err:quartz:GetClassMediaFile Media class not found
0009:err:winediag:MIDIMAP_drvOpen No software synthesizer midi port found, Midi sound output probably won't work.
0009:fixme:gstreamer:GST_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0041:err:gstreamer:push_data Sending returned: -2
0041:fixme:quartz:FileAsyncReader_WaitForNext Returned: 258 (00000000)
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:strmbase:TransformFilterImpl_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:err:msvideo:ICLocate Required media codec 'vidc I420' not found!
0009:fixme:strmbase:TransformFilterImpl_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:DSoundRender_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {56a86897-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770}!
0040:fixme:quartz:DSoundRender_UpdatePositions Underrun of data occurred!
0009:err:quartz:GetClassMediaFile Media class not found
0009:fixme:gstreamer:GST_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0049:err:gstreamer:push_data Sending returned: -2
0049:fixme:quartz:FileAsyncReader_WaitForNext Returned: 258 (00000000)
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:strmbase:TransformFilterImpl_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:err:msvideo:ICLocate Required media codec 'vidc I420' not found!
0009:fixme:strmbase:TransformFilterImpl_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:DSoundRender_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {56a86897-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770}!
003f:fixme:quartz:DSoundRender_UpdatePositions Underrun of data occurred!
```

plz help

I want to play gta vc